# /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /node_modules/snappy/build/Release/binding.node)

Tags: node.js, npm, gcc, loopback4

I am running a loopback4 project inside a docker container which runs on centos 7 version. I have installed gcc inside docker but its still giving below error due to gcc version issue as CXXABI_1.3.9 is missing in gcc@4.8

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /node_modules/snappy/build/Release/binding.node)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.wrappedLoad [as _load] (/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:373:24)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at bindings (/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/snappy/snappy.js:2:34)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.wrappedLoad [as _load] (/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:373:24)
```

I cannot upgrade gcc due to some constraint to include CXXABI_1.3.9 so i started tracking down npm packages which were using CXXABI_1.3.9 and installed it on root level. Current package.json looks like below:

```
"dependencies": {
"@loopback/boot": "3.1.1",
"@loopback/core": "2.13.0",
"@loopback/repository": "3.2.1",
"@loopback/rest": "8.0.0",
"@loopback/rest-explorer": "3.0.4",
"@loopback/service-proxy": "3.0.4",
"gt-common": "1.0.2",
"kafka-node": "5.0.0",
"loopback-connector-mongodb": "^5.5.0",
"loopback-connector-rest": "^3.7.0",
"newrelic": "^6.14.0",
"tslib": "2.1.0",
"snappy": "6.3.5",
"bindings": "1.5.0",
"nan": "2.14.2",
"prebuild-install": "5.3.0"
}
```

But it did not work. Can someone please help me to resolve the above issue by changing the npm package's version which is using the CXXABI_1.3.9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm facing it as well